# How to assign an array within a smarty template file?

Tags: php, smarty

I was wondering if it was possible to assign an array to a variable within a Smarty template file? I have tried this

```
{assign var='file' value = array('dir','doc','exe')}
```

But when I print out the array it produces this:

```
array(\'dir\',\'doc\',\'exe\')
```

How can I stop Smarty escaping the array values?

Comment: I have ran through this problem and came up with a solution earlier. The solution I came up with is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336840/shorten-smarty-if-statements/11337280)

Answer (score 53):

```
{php}
  $this->assign("array", array('dir','doc','exe'));
{/php}

{foreach from=$array item=item}
  {$item}
{/foreach}
```

From **Smarty v.3** new syntax is available

```
{$array = ['item1','item2',$item3]}
```

see for more details : http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Comment: If you use {php} then what is the meaning of using smarty? You should not use {php} inside template until it is the only option. @Jenski 's solution is perfect

Comment: Make sure NOT to put a comma (,) behind the last element. I was copying the array from php which was causing an syntax error.

Comment: It is also possible to assign variable manually to template vars: {php}$this->_tpl_vars['my_array'] = ['var1', 'var2'];{/php}

Answer (score 45):

I just found another answer [here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1252&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15) that allows you to do this without the use of [{php} tags](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.php.php) (recommended by Smarty)

```
{assign var='icon' value=','|explode:"dir,doc,exe"}
```

still open to more ideas though...

Comment: this method do not allow to assign associative array

Comment: +1 - thanks.  This was exactly what we needed to address an issue in our hacky third-party CMS.

Comment: For version 3 of smarty see Mituha's answer.

Comment: This answers precisely what the question asks.

Comment: Is there a function I could use to get an empty array?

Answer (score 9):

what about `{$system=['freebsd','windows','macosx','linux']}`?

Comment: This works in Smarty v3: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Answer (score 0):

its not right way to write a code with in smarty template file. you should create a array in php and then get the values from smarty.

```
This is the right way to create a standard development code. like.
```

**PHP:**

```
public function arrSam(){
    $colors = array( 0 => '#1f1f1f', 1 => '#696969', 2 => '#878787', 3 => '#b4b4b4', 4 => '#d2d2d2', 5 => '#f0f0f0', 6 => '#ffffff');
    $smarty->assign('colors', $colors);
}
```

**Smarty:**

```
{assign var=colors value=$smarty->arrSam()}
{$colors|print_r}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$smarty->assign("lat",$lat);

{foreach $lat as $latlongval}
    {assign var="myArray" value=","|explode:$latlongval} 
    {$myArray['0']}
    {$myArray['1']}
{/foreach}
```