# Array to string conversion smarty template

Tags: php, arrays, string, smarty

Hello I have the Array to string conversion erro with this code:

index.php:

Code:

```
$hoArr = array(1,2,3); 
foreach ($hoArr as $hid) { 
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "zabbixtest"); 
    if (!$mysqli) { 
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT errors_from FROM hosts WHERE hostid = '$hid'"; 
    $re = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re)) { 
        $query_times[] = $row['errors_from']; 


    } 

     mysqli_free_result($re); 
    mysqli_close($mysqli); 


} 
 $smarty->assign('query_times',$query_times);
```

and index.tpl:

Code:

```
<p>{$query_times}</p>
```

I have no idea whats wrong with it..

Comment: `$query_times = $row['errors_from'];`. If you need the string only.

Comment: use `foreach()` to display `$query_times` in your index.tpl

Comment: foreach gives the same error and I need every record from the array so ` $query_times = $row['errors_from']; ` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to assign an array with `$smarty->assign` but you can only assign a string.

Use this instead:

```
$query_string = implode ( "," , $query_times );
$smarty->assign('query_times',$query_string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it throws the same error :/

Comment: Sorry i tried it again after deleting the cache now it works thank you very much!

Comment: But the target of this was to get this records into a table like this: <td>{$query_times}</td> which is now not working, because its one string do you have any idea to solve that?

Comment: Use this `$query_string = implode ( "</td><td>" , $query_times );`

Comment: I tried that before but that gives me this output:  1442825088<td></td>1442222208<td></td>1443333376

Comment: Yes you are right. Check this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244319/how-to-assign-an-array-within-a-smarty-template-file

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution:

index.php:

```
$query_string = implode ("</td><td>", $query_times );
```

index.html:

```
<table>

    <td>{$query_times}</td>
</table>
```

Now it's in a table :)

Comment: sure it works, because u get this from the Query string: record1</td><td>record2</td> and in the template you add the start and end tag.

Comment: I see.. but it is exactly the same as I said in my comment and you said it did not work.. anyways glad it works for you :)